# .bind или .on в jquery

Tags: jquery

Добрый день.

Чем отличается метод .bind() от .on() в jQuery?

Например:

```
$('div').on('click',function(){...})
$('div').bind('click',function(){...})
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`.on()` - новый метод установки обработчиков событий. Введен в 1.7. Объединяет в себе функциональность `.bind()`, `.live()`, `.delegate()`. Начиная с 1.7 эти три метода считаются устаревшими.

Comment: .live устаревшее?  
разве .live от .on не отличается тем что .live поддерживает элементы добавленные динамически на страницу, а .on - нет ?

Comment: Вы внимательно читаете?

> `.on()` объединяет в себе функциональность .bind(), .live(), .delegate().

То-есть, `.on()` не может отличаться от `.live()`, потому что `.live()` выполняется через `.on()`, и, по сути, является подмножеством. А то что он считается устаревшем это в [офф. документации][1] написано. Ключевое слово "Deprecated".

  [1]: http://api.jquery.com/live/

Comment: on прекрасно работает с динамически добавленными елементами, нужно использовать этот метод для динамики, через делегирование!!!!

Comment: анука заставьте метод .on работать с динамически добавленными элементами http://jsfiddle.net/MEthJ/

Comment: Читаем [мануалы][1] внимательно и делаем так:

    $(document).on('click', '#live', function(){});

А еще можно глянуть в исходник и, к своему удивлению, обнаружить что:

    live: function( types, data, fn ) {
        jQuery( this.context ).on( types, this.selector, data, fn );
        return this;
    },

Плюс ключевик `Deprecated` как бы намекает...

  [1]: http://api.jquery.com/live/

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/MEthJ/35/ - таким образом?

Answer (score 2):

В последнем jQuery метод .bind() считается устаревшим, но еще поддерживающимся, при его вызове происходит вызов .on()

```
bind: function( types, data, fn ) {
        return this.on( types, null, data, fn );
    } //код из jquery-1.7.2
```

Читайте полное описании метода [.on()](http://jquery.page2page.ru/index.php5/On)

Answer (score 1):

По сути одно и тоже, но  с официальной документации

> ```
> As of jQuery 1.7, the .on() method is the preferred method for attaching
> ```
>
> event handlers to a document.